# How can I convert a log4j timestamp to milliseconds in Perl?

Tags: perl, log4j, timestamp

The log4j logs I have contain timestamps in the following format:

```
2009-05-10 00:48:41,905
```

I need to convert it in perl to millseconds since epoch, which in this case would be **124189673005**, using the following gawk function. How do I do it in perl?

I have little or no experience in perl, so appreciate if someone can post an entire script that does this

```
function log4jTimeStampToMillis(log4jts) {
    # log4jts is of the form 2009-03-02 20:04:13,474
    # extract milliseconds that is after the command
    split(log4jts, tsparts, ",");
    millis = tsparts[2];

    # remove - : from tsstr
    tsstr = tsparts[1];
    gsub("[-:]", " ", tsstr);
    seconds = mktime(tsstr);
    print log4jts;
    return seconds * 1000 + millis;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used it, but you might want to check out [Time::ParseDate](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-modules/lib/Time/ParseDate.pm).

Comment: Many thanks. parsedate in the module is same as mktime in gawk, but I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Though I almost always tell people to go use one of the many excellent modules from the CPAN for this, most of them do have one major drawback - speed. If you're parsing a large number of log files in real-time, that can sometimes be an issue. In those cases, rolling your own can often be a more suitable solution, but there are many pitfalls and nuances that must be considered and handled properly. Hence the preference for using a known-correct, proven, reliable module written by somebody else. :)

However, before I even considered my advice above, I looked at your code and had converted it to perl in my head... therefore, here is a more-or-less direct conversion of your gawk code into perl. I've tried to write it as simply as possible, so as to highlight some of the more delicate parts of dealing with dates and times in perl by hand.

```
# import the mktime function from the (standard) POSIX module
use POSIX qw( mktime );

sub log4jTimeStampToMillis {
    my ($log4jts, $dst) = @_;

    # extract the millisecond field
    my ($tsstr, $millis) = split( ',', $log4jts );

    # extract values to pass to mktime()
    my @mktime_args = reverse split( '[-: ]', $tsstr );

    # munge values for posix compatibility (ugh)
    $mktime_args[3] -= 1;
    $mktime_args[4] -= 1;
    $mktime_args[5] -= 1900;
    # print Dumper \@mktime_args; ## DEBUG

    # convert, make sure to account for daylight savings
    my $seconds = mktime( @mktime_args, 0, 0, $dst );

    # return that time as milliseconds since the epoch
    return $seconds * 1000 + $millis;
}
```

One important difference between my code and yours - my log4jTimeStampToMillis subroutine takes **two** parameters:

1. the log timestamp string
2. whether or not that timestamp is using daylight savings time ( 1 for true, 0 for false )

Of course, you could just add code to detect if that time falls in DST or not and adjust automatically, but I was trying to keep it simple. :)

NOTE: If you uncomment the line marked DEBUG, make sure to add "use Data::Dumper;" before that line in your program so it will work.

Here's an example of how you could test that subroutine:

```
my $milliseconds = log4jTimeStampToMillis( "2009-05-10 00:48:41,905", 1 );    
my $seconds = int( $milliseconds / 1000 );
my $local = scalar localtime( $seconds );

print "ms:    $milliseconds\n"; # ms:    1241844521905
print "sec:   $seconds\n";      # sec:   1241844521
print "local: $local\n";        # local: Sat May  9 00:48:41 2009
```

Comment: I already got my solution but your response teaches me a little more perl, I am sure I will come back to this response when writing some perl code. +1

Comment: I won't downvote, but seriously... this probably works... until it doesn't... I can't comment on the speed aspect, but if DateTime is slow, it's because it does USEFUL THINGS.

Answer (score 2):

You should take advantage of the great [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm) package, specifically use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.5000/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm):

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

sub log4jTimeStampToMillis {
    my $log4jts=shift(@_);

    #see package docs for how the pattern parameter works
    my $formatter= new DateTime::Format::Strptime(pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N');
    my $dayObj = $formatter->parse_datetime($log4jts);

    return $dayObj->epoch()*1000+$dayObj->millisecond();
}

print log4jTimeStampToMillis('2009-05-10 10:48:41,905')."\n";
#prints my local version of the TS: 1241952521905
```

This saves you the pain of figuring out DST yourself (although you'll have to pass your server's TZ to Strptime via the `time_zone` parameter).  It also saves you from dealing with leap everything if it becomes relevant (and I'm sure it will).

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
Date time = dateFormat.parse(log4jts);
long millis = time.getTime();
```

Comment: what language is this?  also, check out the code formatter - select your code and click the little `101010` button, it will prettify it.